# Generating qr code image and receiving it from API

Tags: iphone, qr-code

I generated the qr code using the google api chart the image generated in browser when hit api in browser, but how to recieve it in image. I tried with the following code but it is not successfull.

```
+(UIImage *)generateQR:(NSDictionary *)data
{
NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=qr&chs=200x200&chl=%@", [data valueForKey:@"data"]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                [NSURL URLWithString:
                                 [urlStr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                                  NSUTF8StringEncoding]]];

NSString *responseString = [MyEventApi sendRequest:request];
// NSLog(@"response:%@", responseString);
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [responseString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
UIImage *imgData = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:jsonData];
NSLog(@"dict in API-------------%@",imgData);
return imgData;
}
```

Please guide for above.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi here are one GitHub example you can generate QRCODE in app and get as a Image like:-

[image]

please check bellow example may be its help's you my Friend

https://github.com/kuapay/iOS-QR-Code-Generator

Comment: I am geting problem in adding this to my project.

Comment: it is giving error "#include <png.h>" not found but it exists in project.

Answer (score 0):

use like this:

```
img1.image = UIImage.createQRImage(str: "hello world")
img2.image = UIImage.createQRImage(str: "hello world", length: 100)
```

[image]

```swift
public extension UIImage {
   /// 生成二维码图片
    /// 图片放大会模糊
    /// - Parameter str: 二维码内容
    /// - Returns: image
    class func createQRImage(str: String) -> UIImage {
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")!
        filter.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        filter.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
        let outPut = filter.outputImage!
        return UIImage(ciImage: outPut, scale: UIScreen.main.scale, orientation: .up)
    }

    /// 生成指定尺寸高清二维码图片
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - str:
    ///   - length: 图片边长
    /// - Returns:
    class func createQRImage(str: String, length: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard let image = UIImage.createQRCIImage(str: str) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage.createNonInterpolatedImage(image: image, length: length)
    }

    class func createQRCIImage(str: String) -> CIImage? {
        let data = str.data(using: .utf8)
        let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIQRCodeGenerator")
        filter?.setValue(data, forKey: "inputMessage")
        filter?.setValue("H", forKey: "inputCorrectionLevel")
        let outPut = filter?.outputImage
        return outPut
    }

    class func createNonInterpolatedImage(image: CIImage?, length: CGFloat) -> UIImage? {
        guard let image = image else { return nil }
        let extent = image.extent.integral
        let scale = min(length / extent.width, length / extent.height)
        // 1. 创建bitmap
        let w = extent.width * scale
        let h = extent.height * scale
        let cs = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceGray()
        let bitmapRef = CGContext(data: nil, width: Int(w), height: Int(h), bitsPerComponent: 8, bytesPerRow: 0, space: cs, bitmapInfo: CGImageAlphaInfo.none.rawValue)
        let context = CIContext(options: nil)
        if let bitmapImage = context.createCGImage(image, from: extent) {
            bitmapRef?.interpolationQuality = .none
            bitmapRef?.scaleBy(x: scale, y: scale)
            bitmapRef?.draw(bitmapImage, in: extent)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
        // 2. 保存bitmap到图片
        guard let scaledImage = bitmapRef?.makeImage() else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIImage(cgImage: scaledImage)
    }

}
```